# Implementing a slide effect for a UIView

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, slideup

All,

I'm trying desperately to write a method that will animate adding a subview in a kind of "slide up" effect, where the view slides onto the screen from a particular point. I can get a UIImageView to work, but I'm having a heck of a time applying it to a UIPickerView. What happens is, the UIPickerView only moves and animates for about 1/4 of it's height. The UIImageView truly starts w/ a height of 0 and slides up onto the screen.

Here is my code so far:

```
+ (void) slideupView:(UIView*) view duration:(CGFloat) duration completion:(void (^)(BOOL 
                                     finished)) completion {
    CGRect endBounds = view.bounds;
    CGRect startBounds = endBounds;

    startBounds.size.height = 0;

    view.bounds = startBounds;
    view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;
    view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0); 

    CGPoint pos = view.layer.position;
    pos.y += (endBounds.size.height / 2);
    view.layer.position = pos;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0.0        
                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
         animations:^{
             view.bounds = endBounds;
         }
         completion:completion];
}
```

From the things I've read, it sounds like the encouraged approach is to use the bounds rectangle instead of the frame since the frame approach won't work if you've modified the transform.

I've ALSO read that one can't change the height of a UIPickerView, so I'm wondering if that's the reason for this problem. Admittedly, I haven't tried it on any other UIView subclass.

Any thoughts? Is there a better approach? I just want to animate a view onto the screen, similar to presenting a modal view controller's view, except that I don't want it to cover the entire screen. I just want a slide up effect, like when the keyboard appears on the screen.

Thanks!
Justin

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to slide up your view like as the keyboard comes up then you can do it by changing y coordinate of your view by animation.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,460.0f,320.0f,260.0f)];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:[self view] cache:YES];
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,200.0f,320.0f,260.0f)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Simple enough, though I wonder why not using view.frame property?

Comment: But it's not quite as simple as just animating the frame, since I want to begin the animation from an arbitrary point on the screen, not just from off the screen.

Comment: yes its not an easy task to add a view animation from a particular point on screen, it can be possible by a trick that you can use an image to hide your animation at that point but it's depend on your complete screen view.

Comment: you can use fade in effect instead of slide up if you want animation on a particular point

Answer (score 0):

"Bounds" refers to the internal coordinate system of the view itself, whereas "frame" and "center" refer to the position of the view in its parent's coordinate system. So to slide a view onto the screen you'll want to animate either the frame or the center.